# What does firebase realtime database use under the hood for offline capabilities?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, offline-caching

I am curious to know, if firebase uses SQLite under the hood to save its data for offline use or it creates a file saving the data or anything else?

Comment: What platform are you asking about?

Comment: Asking about Android platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android the Firebase Database client uses a SQLite database for its disk based persistence. There is no documentation on this however, as it's seen as an implementation detail that you should not rely on.